# Raytracer -- Why are there speckles on the edges of my spheres?

Tags: raytracing

My raytracer is generating the following image:
[image]

I've checked the normals many times and I'm quite confident that those are not the problem.  Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: What algorithm do You use for intersecting rays with those spheres?

Comment: I apply the inverse of the sphere's transform to the ray, plug the parametric ray equation into the implicit sphere equation, and solve for the distance of the intersection point along the ray .

Comment: share some relevant code, please.   I suspect that you're hitting a "self intersection" problem, given that the speckles are all at points where the ray just grazes the spheres.

Answer (score 1):

What @Alnitak said in the comments. The speckles usually appear because of self intersection. This can also occur during the implementation of shadows as well. If you have implemented shadows do check if the shadow ray generates from the point on the surface, if so add a small constant for example "0.001" to generate your ray a little further than the surface to avoid self-intersection.